# Decoding utf8 literal python

Tags: python, python-3.x, utf-8

I am trying to decode strings in a list of strings, for example `'caf\\xc3\\xab'` what I want if this to be `'café'`.

I tried some things but ran into problems.

when i do:

```
for i in range(len(words):
     words[i] = words[i].decode("utf8")
```

I still need to convert to byte type but how do I do this,

also when I do it like this I need to remove the double backslashes for this to work

```
b'caf\\xc3\\xab'.decode("utf8")
```

Comment: python2's str is bytes, you can just use unicode or ues python3 (in python3 str is unicode)

Comment: I use python3 but read the strings from a file in that specific format

Comment: `words.decode()` is not an in-place operation, you need to capture the return value: `word = word.decode("utf8")`. (Further note: this will only change the value of the loop variable `word`, but not the elements in `words`.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Suppose you have string as follow:

```
bef = 'caf\\xc3\\xab'
```

To convert to '`café`' you can do the following:

```
aft = bef.encode().decode('unicode-escape').encode('latin1').decode('utf-8')
```

Then `print(aft)` should show 'café'